# how to replace word in vi editor globally in ubuntu

Tags: editor, vi

I want to replace the word "windows" globally in `vi` editor, by using any command.

The text to modify is:

```
windows is choice of everyone
windows is choice of student
windows is choice of engineer
windows is choice of web server
```

I tried this command:

```
:1,$s/Windows/UNIX/LINUX/g
```

but it's giving me the error `E488: trailing characters`. What's the problem?

Comment: you can only specify one replacement... your instruction is ambiguous!

Comment: As Zanna says, only one replacement is valid `:1,$ s/Windows/UNIX/g`

Comment: Maybe he wants to replace "Windows" with "UNIX/LINUX"? In that case I guess the slash in the replacement must be escaped, which could probably look like `:1,$ s/Windows/UNIX\/LINUX/g` (I have no idea about vi, just wildly guessing)?

Comment: Or use a different deliminator , there is nothing sacred about "/" . `s_Windows_UNIX/LINUX_g` Personally I find / hard to read worse when it has to be escaped

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you have both Unix and Linux in your command. 
How about:

```
:%s/windows/linux/g
```

or if the replacement string is unix/linux:

```
%s/windows/unix\/linux/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the forward slash in your replacement text with a backslash as in `UNIX\/LINUX`.

As commented by [user:Panther] when using forward slashes in your search/replace strings, it is simpler to use a different delimiter. I prefer to use # so in your case it would be:

```
:% s#windows#UNIX/LINUX#
```

The `g` suffix is only needed if you expect to see `windows` more than once on a single line which your example does not show.